# How to make a text box to accept only number based on a condition?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

How to make a `textbox` to accept only number?
when my `label.text` is **gms** or **rs** or **knot**, then  respective `textbox` accept only **numbers**.
when `label.text` is character it has allow only **character value**.

```
Example:gms: 1200
        character:black
        knot:5
        rs:80
        character:pink
```

This order may change based on the selection. 
 And please post the ASPX code too.

Comment: Please frame the question in proper words.

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732455/how-to-allow-only-integers-in-a-textbox

Comment: if you want gms rs know then make a selectbox and put them right to textbox. If your requirement doesn't match this then let me know.

Comment: where do you want to check the values in javascript or c#. Kindly put your html also.

Comment: i going to check this c#

Answer (score 1):

Can you add the KeyPress event for the corresponding textbox? 
So that you can do the following!

```
private void textBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
   if ((label.Text.Equals("gms") || label.Text.Equals("rs") || label.Text.Equals("knot"))
   { 
      if (!char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
      {
         e.Handled = true;
      }
   }
   else
   {
      if (!char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar))
      {
         e.Handled = true;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: hi @vanest i have one doubt.In .aspx page should i have to add textbox_keypress property .If i have to add that too please post that coding too

Comment: This sample is for windows application! :-(

Answer (score 0):

Apply a regular validator on your text box with validation expression `"^[0-9]"` which accept only numbers
initially make it disabled

you can then enable disable it according to the text of your label making the text box to accept all or only numbers

Answer (score 0):

Try this, maybe this is something that you're looking for:

```
private void textBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
           if ((label.Text.Equals("gms") || label.Text.Equals("rs") || label.Text.Equals("knot")))
           { 
              if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != '.')
                {
                    e.Handled = true;
                }

              // only allow one decimal point
              if (e.KeyChar == '.' && (sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1)
              {
                  e.Handled = true;
              }
           }
        }
```

Comment: how to call this text_keypress function from ASPX page

Comment: Here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13158752/fire-event-on-enter-key-press-for-a-asp-net-textbox

Comment: @Sylca : I think KeyPressEventArgs cannot be called in web applications (System.Web doesn't have definition for that, its a member of System.Windows.Forms)...

Answer (score 0):

Although you want to implement the solution in [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23). Better suggestion would be is to implement in [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript).

Add simple javascript function to in `aspx` page and no code in codebehind file.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var arrForNum = ['gms', 'rs', 'knot']; //Your list of label texts for Number only textboxes
// Now traverse for all textboxes where u want to add some restrictons

$('body').find('.customonly').each(function () {
    var id = this.id;
    var res = $('label[for=' + id + ']').text();    
   // check if its the array we declared else it will be charecters only. 
    if ($.inArray(res, arrForNum) >= 0) {
        $(this).forceNumeric();  // Added simple function in fiddle.
       //You can apply any other function here if required.
    } else {
        $(this).forceCharecters('chars');
    }
  });
});
```

Check the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pcgupta17/BZkxL/2/) for detailed code.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void txt3_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{

    for (int h = 58; h <= 127; h++)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == h)             //58 to 127 is alphabets tat will be         blocked
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }

    }

    for(int k=32;k<=47;k++)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == k)              //32 to 47 are special characters tat will 
        {                                  be blocked
            e.Handled = true;
        }

    }



}
```

try this is very simple