# How to add event when press enter using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have solution when add text in **textbox** and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> the
 **textbox** content inserted in DB , I tried to get the best solution for
 that but I couldn't . so How can I add event when press <kbd>Enter</kbd>?.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txt_home">Add Comment</asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13158752/fire-event-on-enter-key-press-for-a-asp-net-textbox

Comment: That's what we all here for to give each other a hand :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in asp.net the simplest way is to use a Panel that warps the textboxes, and what ever user fills, and set `DefaultButton` to the action you wont when the user press <kbd>Enter</kbd> for the included text boxes.

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlAct" DefaultButton="Button1">
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txt_home">Add Comment</asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
</asp:Panel>
```

Of course you can use custom javascript to capture the <kbd>Enter</kbd> and make custom post back, but asp.net all ready gives you a safe and "ready to use solution".

Answer (score -2):

The most usual event in a textbox is the [TextChangedEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I suppose this is what you are looking for. The link provided, gives you also this example:

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Label1.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(TextBox1.Text);
}
```

Alternatively, you could use javascript to capture a [keydown](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeydown.asp) or a [keyup](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp) event. Then you could check if the key pressed is the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. For example:

```
$(".input1").keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        // Do something
    }
});
```

Hope I helped!