# In aspx how to trigger button click event when press "Enter" on a textbox while the button click event defined in source cs file

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

While, I want to trigger `btnSearchSuiteGroup_Click` event when pressing "enter" on `txtSuiteGroupName` which described in aspx, code below:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSuiteGroupName" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" CssClass="DD" onkeypress="return searchKeyPress(event)"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnSearchSuiteGroup" runat="server" Text="Search"  CssClass="DD" Width="64px" onclick="btnSearchSuiteGroup_Click" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function searchKeyPress(e) {

        // look for window.event in case event isn't passed in
        if (typeof e == 'undefined' && window.event) { e = window.event; }
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            document.getElementById('<%=btnSearchSuiteGroup.ClientID%>').click();
        }
    }
</script>
```

While, the `btnSearchSuiteGroup_Click` is defined in the source cs file:

```
protected void btnSearchSuiteGroup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.LinqDataSource1.WhereParameters["SuiteGroupName"].DefaultValue = this.txtSuiteGroupName.Text;
    this.GridView1.DataBind();
    if (GridView1.Rows.Count == 0)
        Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>window.alert('No record found!')</script>");
}
```

When I browse the website, the keypress on the textbox cannot initiate the button click event, anything wrong in the code?

Comment: The above code triggers `btnSearchSuiteGroup_Click` for me. Can you try to debug and set a break point inside `btnSearchSuiteGroup_Click`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use `Panel` you would not need to use any javascript function. You can specify default `button` Id for panel like below

```
    <asp:Panel runat="server" DefaultButton="btnSearchSuiteGroup">
       <asp:TextBox ID="txtSuiteGroupName" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" CssClass="DD">          
       </asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSearchSuiteGroup" runat="server" Text="Search"  CssClass="DD" Width="64px" onclick="btnSearchSuiteGroup_Click" />
        </asp:Button>
    </asp:Panel>
```

OfCourse you can have Multiple `panels` on single page for assigning different default `buttons` for separate `panels`!

For More On [Panel.DefaultButton Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.defaultbutton.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following method:
1. Create a function 'ButtonClick' and put all the code in 'btnSearchSuiteGroup_Click' function into it.
2. Add 'onkeypress' event for the textbox 'txtSuiteGroupName' by looking at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13158752/fire-event-on-enter-key-press-for-a-asp-net-textbox)
3. Whenever the above event is fired, see if the entered key is 'Enter'.
4. If the key is 'Enter' key, call the function 'ButtonClick'.