# Client side keypress handling event, set focus function, and __doPostBack ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I'm trying to do the following :

- First, a textBox get the focus on page load (no problem here)
- Then, when `ENTER` button is pressed inside that textBox, it switch focus to the second textBox.
- Finally, when `ENTER` is pressed in that second textBox, it does a postback and reahes code behind event just like when you press a classic `<asp:button />`

Based on :

[Fire event on enter key press for a textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13158752/fire-event-on-enter-key-press-for-a-textbox)

and

[JavaScript set focus to HTML form element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500704/javascript-set-focus-to-html-form-element)

I managed to come up with :

### HTML :

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtNNoSerie" runat="server"  Width="150px" ClientIDMode="Static" onkeypress="EnterEventFirst(event)" AutoPostBack="false"></asp:TextBox>             
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtNNoIdentification" runat="server" Width="150px" ClientIDMode="Static" onkeypress="EnterEventSecond(event)" AutoPostBack="false"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:Button id="btnAjouter" CssClass="ms-Button ms-Button--primary" onclick="btnAjouter_click" Text="+" ForeColor="White" runat="server"  Width="30px" />

    <input type="text" id="txtTest" /> <%-- Just for tests --%>
```

### JS :

```
  function EnterEventFirst(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 13) {
          document.getElementById('txtTest').value = 'got it';
          document.getElementById('<%=txtNNoIdentification.ClientID%>').focus();
      }
  } 



  function EnterEventSecond(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 13) {
          document.getElementById('txtTest').value = 'Again';
          __doPostBack('<%=btnAjouter.ClientID%>', "");
      }
  }
```

### Code behind :

```
    protected void btnAjouter_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

JavaScript functions are reached, because i can see "got it" and "Again" in the test TextBox, but just for half a second and then it desapear... The __DoPostBack funtion does not work.

Looks like when you press enter in a textBox, it automaticaly does a useless postback and page reload... And that is where i'm stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, textBox automaticaly postBack when enter is pressed, ok then.

I did it all on server side, I hate this but i kinda had no choice :

```
        txtNNoSerie.Focus();
        if (txtNNoSerie.Text != "")
            txtNNoIdentification.Focus();
        if (txtNNoSerie.Text != "" && txtNNoIdentification.Text != "")
            btnAjouter_click(this, new EventArgs());
```

Server side code... If anyone can show me some working client side code i'll take it...

Comment: __doPostBack('<%=btnAjouter.ClientID%>', ""); does the postback not textbox automatically !

Comment: @Navid i removed the __doPostBack , and still, when i push enter inside a text box, it postback, probably because of runat="server"

Answer (score 1):

Use ClientID instead of UniqueID.

Comment: Ok, now the focus work, but anyway the page Reload cancels everything

Comment: it focuses for half a second, then the focus is back on the first textBox

Comment: your problem is unclear !
you have only two textbox and no submit button.
you press Enter in first textbox , and then in second textbox .
when you press Enter in second one it runs __dopostback function which causes the form to be submited and page to be refreshed.

what is the problem here ?

Comment: there is a button, but when someone press enter in the second textbox, it's just as if he pressed that button.

Comment: that's because of your own code  ( __doPostBack('<%=btnAjouter.ClientID%>', ""); )
this line does the postback not textbox itself.
unless you set the property of Autopostback=true ;

Comment: I removed that, and still, postBack, i even placed a textbox in an empty page, same result.

Comment: I saw it's because of the `runat=server` but if i don't specify it, my control is not visible from code behind, so i'm done for